# Add/Edit webform on same page?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, webforms

I am designing a pretty complex webform with Master/Detail structure. Is it a good move to keep the add/edit form on the same webpage ?

My current scenario has 2 separate web pages (add new & edit), On add new  page the add details is disabled until user saves the master.

On edit page everything works out of the box.
[image: Current Scenario Add web form]
[image: Current scenario Edit web form]

> 1. Both the forms have exactly similar controls
> 2. I am thinking about the following new structure - Same webpage for Add/Edit (User adds master
>      record (add mode) -> Saves -> Gets
>      redirected to the same page with edit
>      mode-> Can add,update delete new
>      Details or Update the master he
>      just entered
> 3. What do you guys prefer in such scenarios ?
>      [image: Proposed structure Add Webform]
>      [image: Proposed structure Edit Webform]

On a note, separate webform for edit page means duplicating everything
with just some minor changes to Save/Edit functionality. Also for the details I have to provide Add/Edit/Delete on the same page anyway

Thanks Damien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a good idea. My experience is that add/edit might look quite similar, but they have things that differ. The number of differences usually grows as the project grows.

Use different forms, or you'll end up with spaghetti.

You might however move parts that will not change to user controls and include those in both pages.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What do you mean by 'You might however move parts that will not change to user controls and include those in both pages.' ? Does that mean using 'userControls' on both pages for some functionality say 'Add details' etc ?

Comment: yes. Create one user control for "Add Details" if it will not differ.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use JQuery and Open Popups for such operations for new and edit case. This will also make reuse of your controls.

Comment: Thanks. This is just a rough sketch, the main question boils down to using a single webpage or 2 separate ones for Add/Edit in master/detail scenarios.

Comment: Use single and drag drop buttons will open the pop up using JQuery.

Comment: can you explain what will be the benefits with a single form in the long run?

Comment: 1. Avoids server trips        2. light weight application i.e. In the similar fashion you can code other modules.    3. Reuse-ability of code because you will open the add/edit in same Pop Up using J-Query etc.